# Finding the Max Term in a loop without if

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, max

I looked and could not find the answer to my question so here it is. I have written a loop that outputs a power rating for different frequencys. The largest power rating is somewhere in the middle of the loop output. I need to indicate which is the largest by printing max next to it. However I have been limited and am not allowed to use an if condition. How would I go about getting my program to determine the largest output and mark it with text? I am using python.

```
while frQncy < 24.0:                                                             
    TERAHZ_TO_HZ = frQncy * 10.0**12                                              
    v_ = TERAHZ_TO_HZ                                                                 
    I_ = ((2.0 * h_ * v_**3) / (c_**2)) * (1.0/(math.exp((h_ * v_) / (k_ * Tk))-1.0))   
    print "Frequency: %.3g Spectral Radiance: %.4E" % (frQncy, I_)                       
    frQncy += 0.2
```

Comment: to add challenge to the problem. It is an intro class that has not dealt with IF statements yet so we were limited to using only what has been covered so far.

Comment: Fake it with a one iteration while loop? ;D

Comment: `max_val = max(new_val,max_val)` ... maybe useful ...

Comment: Teaching *while* before *if* seems backwards to me, but oh well.  Joran's suggestion sounds right: there's a *max()* function that you can use.

Comment: I've indented the program because it wasn't showing up properly on SO; did I do it right?  I'm assuming that the body of the while loop are the rest of the lines.

Comment: yes it looks good. Unfortunately we have yet to cover the max() function either. However there is nothing saying I cannot use it. Could someone give me an example of its use?

Answer (score 2):

You could put all the frequencies in an iterable and use the built in [max() function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max)